# remapping svg to different coordinate system

Tags: matplotlib, svg, gimp, inkscape

I have an svg that I'd like to display using nonlinear coordinates, on semilog axes for instance. Is there a way to do this using e.g. matplotlib,inkscape, gimp that would avoid diving into the details of the svg format, or alternatively does svg allow for such transforms already?  I'd like to retain the svg-nature to avoid pixellation of greatly-magnified parts.

Comment: SVG does not support non-affine transforms.

Comment: For use in the browser, [tag:d3.js] has a [scale module](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/main/README.md) that offers this sort of abstraction.